# Entity Framework 4.0 Self Tracking Load Navigation Properties

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, self-tracking-entities

I have this code for my Data Access class where I want to load all the Patients where they some should have, Patient.Addresses, Patient.Examinations, Examinations.LeftEye, Examinations.RightEye....

How to Load all the related data with a patient? I havent managed to load even the address.

This is the current code:

```
            db.Patients.Include("Addresses");
            db.Patients.Include("Examinations");

            db.Examinations.Include("LeftEyePictures");
            db.Examinations.Include("RightEyePictures");

            List<Patient> list = db.Patients.ToList();

            list.ForEach(p => p.ChangeTracker.ChangeTrackingEnabled = true);

            return list;
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Include` must be part of the query!

```
List<Patient> list = db.Patients.Include("Addresses")
                                .Include("Examinations.LeftEyePicutres")
                                .Include("Examinations.RightEyePicutres")
                                .ToList();
```

Comment: This was my first approach, do I set the string parameter of the Include using the navigation properties name right? Or the name of the table of the model?

Comment: You must use names of navigation properties.

Answer (score 1):

there is two ways:
 1st:
 enable lazzy loading before loading

```
db.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
List<Patient> list = db.Patients.ToList(); // here is All Patients with Linked objects
db.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

Then disable, if you dont need it

2nd:Handload

```
   db.Patients.Addresses.Load()
   db.Patients.Examinations.Load()
   db.Examinations.LeftEyePictures.Load()
   db.Examinations.RightEyePicturesLoad()
```

you can chesk before loading: (this or similar)

```
   if(db.Patients.Addresses.IsLoaded==false)
      db.Patients.Addresses.Load
```

Comment: 2nd Handload I cant find any db.Patients.Address property or any Load() method

Comment: Self tracking entities don't support lazy loading and calling Load for each property will result in N+1 problem.